# Storing multiple zeros in an int array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to implementing BigInteger logic in Java.  I am getting input in the form of String and converting and storing it to an int array.

Now while performing addition of two integer arrays, the problem occurs.

For example:

```
int first_array[0]=999999999
int Second_array[0]=1;
```

I will get the addition value as `1000000000`, where I will take 10th digit as carryover.

```
carry_over=(first_array[0]+Second_array[0])/1000000000 ;//1

add_array[0]=(first_array[0]+Second_array[0])%1000000000 ;//000000000
```

My expectation for `add_array[0]` is `000000000`, but its storing as 0.  That is, it's storing it as a single zero instead of nine zeros.

Is there any way I can resolve the problem?

Comment: 000000000 and 0 are the same value, you have an int array, not a string array.

Comment: How do you plan on storing the base positions?  For base 10 you have ones, tens, hundreds, thousands, etc...how do you plan on representing that here?  (This concept will get you past your confusion.)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard i know that ,so only i am asking anyway to fix it

Comment: Just look at the official source code of BigInteger and you'll see how it is made : http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java

Comment: A number doesn't have a format, only strings have a format. If you want it to print as "000000000" you need to store that as a String.  If you want to store the value 0 and have it print the number with leading zeros, you would so that in your toString() method.

Comment: BTW BigInteger doesn't use powers of 10 to store it's integers, it uses 64-bit long values.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same 000000000 than 0. The result of the arrays should be the same. The only problem you have is when printing the number as a string override the toString() method in your "BigInteger" class so for each position it calls String.format("%09d%n", n). Then you will represent any number in n with 9 digits

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse *formatting* with *data*.

000000000 is the same as 0.

Leading zeros can cause you problems as a leading zero implies an *octal* literal.